# Why can't I find XCTest/XCTest.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tdd, xctest

I am trying to get started with tdd within Xcode, and followed a very nice [tutorial](http://www.preeminent.org/steve/iOSTutorials/XCTest/).

Everything went well. However, when I want to make a command line application (in c) project in Xcode a separate test-folder was not created.

I want to build a random graph implementation, and my project graph consists of main.c, graph.h and graph.c. I decided to add a test-file (objective C test file case).

Here, I have the import XCTest/XCTest.h but when running (Product->run) I get the error that XCTest/XCTest.h is not found. I also do not get to run test mode (Product-test).

why is that header-file not found? and how do I fix it?

Comment: I solved it by only creating projects incorporating the cocoa-framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

XCTest/XCTest.h will work for testTarget only not for other targets try to remove targets for your xxxtest.m file. you can do that by removeing it form compileSources of that target

Comment: What if I'm trying to build a framework for Test Helpers though? My target isn't an xctest it's a framework.